# Git branching strategy for releasing major releases

Tags: git, bower

I have a git project with I have published to bower. The project supports different versions of Polymer. The master branch is a Polymer 1 element and in a side branch (called 2.0-preview), a Polymer 2 element. Over the course of time, both branches have had their own individual commits and bug fixes.

I would now like to deprecate the Polymer 1 element such that when a user does `bower install`, they would download the Polymer 2 element that resides on the side branch. What is the recommended way to make this happen? Should I simply rename the side branch to master, merge or rebase the branches? Thanks.

Comment: Do you still want/need whatever is not on the Polymer 2 branch?

Comment: hi @kelvin yes, for users who have not migrated and still need the Polymer 1 element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I went with was to

1. Banch master out to a 1.0 branch
2. Merge the 2.0-preview branch
   into master

This retained the history and also avoided the flow-on effects which could cause potential breaks to my collaborators.

**Note:** For projects that involve master and side branches being worked on parallely, it is a good idea to continuously integrate master into the side branches either by merging or rebasing to avoid problematic integration/merge issues later during the final merge.